# sqlite count results based whitin timeline

Tags: c#, sqlite, date, datetime

Hope someone can help with some advise
i'm trying to get a SQLite query to count the occurrence of an value in a time frame for 15min interval and return distinct count

My Data looks something like this

> > > ---------DATA----------
>
> ```
> Connection_Time         Last_Accessed               UserName   
> 2015-01-12 06:00:00     2015-01-12 07:00:00          JamesG    
> 2015-01-12 06:10:00     2015-01-12 06:12:00          JohnH
> 2015-01-12 06:32:00     2015-01-12 07:00:00          JohnH
> ```

This is the result I would like

> ```
> Result                      count
> "2015-01-12 06:00:00"         2
> "2015-01-12 06:15:00"         1
> "2015-01-12 06:30:00"         2
> "2015-01-12 06:45:00"         2
> "2015-01-12 07:00:00"         2
> ```

With my current select I get a result but it doesn't consider the timespan between Connection_Time and Last Accessed

> ```
> select datetime((strftime('%s', currentUsers.Connection_Time) / 300) * 300, 'unixepoch') >    >     interval,
> count(distinct(UserName)) cnt
> from currentUsers
> group by interval
> order by interval
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute all the intervals, you need a [CTE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) (this requires a recent enough SQLite version):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
min_time(t) AS (
  SELECT datetime((strftime('%s',
                            (SELECT MIN(Connection_Time)
                             FROM currentUsers)
                  ) / 300) * 300,
                  'unixepoch')
),
max_time(t) AS (
  SELECT datetime((strftime('%s',
                            (SELECT MAX(Last_Access)
                             FROM currentUsers)
                  ) / 300) * 300,
                  'unixepoch')
),
intervals(t) AS (
  SELECT t FROM min_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT datetime(t, '+15 minutes')
  FROM intervals
  WHERE t <= (SELECT t FROM max_time)
)
SELECT t AS interval,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserName)
        FROM currentUsers
        WHERE Connection_Time < datetime(intervals.t, '+15 minutes')
          AND Last_Accessed >= intervals.t
       ) AS Count
FROM intervals;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply let me try and come back to you

Comment: Hi @CL
hope you can help me if you have a moment 
the answer you gave was great but I might have missed something 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156732/sqlite-rolling-timestamp-count