# SQLite Rolling TimeStamp Count

Tags: c#, sqlite

Hi I have asked this question before but might nit have phrased it right 
hope someone can help me

i'm trying to get a SQLite query to count the occurrence of an value in a Rolling TimeFrame and return a distinct count

My Data looks something like this

> > > ---------DATA----------
>
> ```
> TimeStamp         UserName   
> 2015-01-12 06:07:00     JamesG    
> 2015-01-12 06:07:00     JohnH
> 2015-01-12 06:10:00     JohnH
> 2015-01-12 06:10:00     James
> 2015-01-12 06:10:00     Dean
> 2015-01-12 06:10:00     Alicia
> 2015-01-12 06:12:00     Ann
> 2015-01-12 06:12:00     Dean
> 2015-01-12 06:12:00     JohnH
> ```

This is the result I would like

> ```
> Result                      count
> "2015-01-12 06:07:00"         2
> "2015-01-12 06:10:00"         4
> "2015-01-12 06:12:00"         3
> ```

With my current select I get a result but it doesn't consider Timestamp it generates 5min intervals

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE
> min_time(t) AS (
> SELECT datetime((strftime('%s',
> (SELECT  MIN(TimeStamp)
> FROM ConcurrentUsers)
> ) / 300) * 300,
> 'unixepoch')
> ),
> max_time(t) AS (
> SELECT datetime((strftime('%s',
> (SELECT  MAX(TimeStamp)
> FROM ConcurrentUsers)
> ) / 300) * 300,
> 'unixepoch')
> ),
> intervals(t) AS (
> SELECT t FROM min_time
> UNION ALL
> SELECT datetime(t, '+5 minutes')
> FROM intervals
> WHERE t <= (SELECT t FROM max_time)
> )
> SELECT t AS interval,
> (SELECT COUNT(Distinct(strftime('%M',TimeStamp)))
> FROM ConcurrentUsers
> WHERE TimeStamp < datetime(intervals.t, '+5 minutes') AND TimeStamp >= intervals.t AS Count
> FROM intervals where interval >= date('now')
> ORDER BY date(interval) DESC
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

I think I found the solution

> ```
> WITH C AS (SELECT DISTINCT TimeStamp FROM ConcurrentUsers)
> SELECT Count(Distinct(UserName))TheCount,TimeStamp FROM ConcurrentUsers where TimeStamp >= date('now') 
> Group by TimeStamp
> ORDER BY date(TimeStamp) DESC
> ```

Comment: `DISTINCT` ...where in the query are you even selecting Distinct Count(*)` ? [SQL Basics Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

Comment: Hi Sorry I have redone this query 100 times, this query does not give me results based on my timestamp it generates intervals of 5 min

Comment: so does that mean you did it `100 times correctly || Incorrectly` what does that statement mean..?

Comment: ok I mean I tried 100 different ways that's why the statement does not have the distinct will update date it shortly
 "2015-01-26 00:00:00" "0" 
"2015-01-26 00:05:00" "0"

"2015-01-26 00:10:00" "0"
"2015-01-26 00:15:00" "0"
"2015-01-26 00:20:00" "0"
"2015-01-26 00:25:00" "0"
"2015-01-26 00:30:00" "0"
"2015-01-26 00:35:00" "0"
"2015-01-26 00:40:00" "0"
"2015-01-26 00:45:00" "0"
"2015-01-26 00:50:00" "0"
"2015-01-26 00:55:00" "0"
"2015-01-26 01:00:00" "0"

Comment: Im not a SQL expert 
hence hoping someone who is could assist me with this not sure what i'm missing

Comment: that's why there is a thing called `Google` I am not an Sql Expert either but when I want to find examples on how to do something I do a google search and read through the examples as well as try to understand what it is I am not only `writing but also reading` please do not expect others to just provide you an answer and `Im not a Sql expert` is not an excuse.. if someone provides you a working solution how will you be able to maintain it if requested to make changes if you don't try to write something on your own as well as understand what it is that you've written.??

Comment: I hear you and that is not my intension 
I have googled and googled believe me this is the last resort

Comment: well I posted a link and when you do a google search it's as easy as `Sql Server Select Distinct Examples`

Comment: I hear you but my question isn't how to do a distinct 

I want a return of multiple Counts based on Timestamp with distinct values in a certain column in that Timestamp

Comment: Why is the result `2` for `06:12`?

Comment: @CL 
im doing it on the timestamp I get the data

Comment: But I must thank you @CL 
With the help you gave me last time I think I figured it out with my current Req. if you look at the updated post with the solution at the end of my question if you can just check that for me it would be great !

Comment: There are three rows with `06:12`. Why `2`?

Comment: Sorry Typo you are right there are 3 Rows

Comment: I typed up what I wanted from the Query before I got the solution fixed it now in the Question

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856266/linq-aggregate-and-group-by-periods-of-time using count.